# Игнорирование "(" и ")" в re.sub()

Tags: python, re

Я не совсем понимаю как обращаться с функциями регулярных выражений... поэтому прошу помощи у знающих людей...

У меня есть задача в текстовом файле в котором записаны какие-либо значения в формате "name = 'text'" находить и заменять те или иные значения. Под данную задачу я нашел вот этот [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641746/19063057) и немного доработал его.

```
def replace(pattern, subst):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            if pattern in line:
                pattern = line.replace('\n', '')
                print(pattern)
                split = line.split('=')
                print(split)

    file_handle = open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    file_string = file_handle.read()
    file_handle.close()

    file_string = (
        re.sub(pattern, split[0] + '= ' + "'" + subst + "'", file_string))

    file_handle = open(file, 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    file_handle.write(file_string)
    file_handle.close()
```

И все бы ничего... но ингода в строках встречаются "(" и ")"... строка просто не заменяется... к сути дела... можно ли как-то заставить игнорировать круглые скобки?

Ответ для Namerek:
И так... Допустим в файле у меня есть строка "Name = 'Bob'"
Мне нужно поменять в этой строке 'Bob' на 'Jhon'
Я взываю функцию `replace('Name', 'Jhon')`
В таком случае все работает корректно и строка станет "Name = 'Jhon'"
Но в случае если в строке будут круглые скобки "Name = 'Bob(Blob)'"
При вызове функции `replace('Name', 'Jhon')`, строка остаётся неизменной.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста исходный текст и результат который Вы ожидаете после работы регулярного выражения

Comment: Не код, а каша. Или мне одному так показалось? Если я правельно понял логику автора, то блок с file_handle должен быть выше цикла и проблема с оступами

Comment: @Namerek  я ответил вам в основном вопросе

Comment: @СергейШашко "Не код, а каша" Может быть┐(￣∀￣)┌                                            
Если у вас есть более лаконичные варианты... то я готов их выслушать)                  
"проблема с оступами" А собственно где?...

Comment: Нужно чтобы текст в скобках остался?

Comment: @LoTerFox "Не код, а каша." это мягко сказано, уж простите деревенского дурочка.

Comment: @Namerek Нет, проблема в том что если в строке есть скобки, то строка остаётся неизменной.
я приложу 2 скриншота...  Может так понятнее будет
Вариант без скобок: https://pastenow.ru/GWFNC Со скобами в строке: https://pastenow.ru/GWFNI

Comment: @Namerek вы мне очень помогли, Cпасибо<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.txt`

```
Name = 'Bob(Blob)'
City = 'Berlin'
Country = 'Germany'
```

```py
import re

def replace_param(field_name, value):
    with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as source:
        modified_data = re.sub(
            rf"(?<=^{field_name} = ').*?(?=')", value, source.read(), flags=re.M
        )


    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as destination:
        destination.write(
            modified_data
        )

replace_param('Name', 'John')
```

`output.txt`

```
Name = 'John'
City = 'Berlin'
Country = 'Germany'
```

---

**Кстати, если паредположить, что речь идет о, допустим, профиле пользователя, в котором нет параметров с одинаковым именем, то можно предложить еще одно решение без регулярных выражений (помятуя правило о неэффективности стрельбы из пушки по воробьям)**

```
def split_line(line: str):
    if ' = ' in line:
        return line.strip().split(' = ', 1)


def join_line(params: tuple):
    return ' = '.join(params)


def replace_param(field_name, value):
    with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as source:
        src = dict(filter(None, map(split_line, source.readlines())))

    src[field_name] = f"'{value}'"

    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as destination:
        destination.write(
            '\n'.join(map(join_line, src.items()))
        )


replace_param('Name', 'John')
```

> *При вышеуказанных данных, даст аналогичный эффект ...
>
> Кроме того, даст возможность добавить параметр которого небыло*

Comment: Не успел я ответить по поводу нескольких значений... так вы уже добавили вариант решения))) Вы прям читаете мысли))) единственное что... в данном варианте изменяется именно "Bob", а мне бы заменять полностью "Bob(Blob)" на то что будет передано в функции вторым значением.
То есть `replace_param('Name', 'John')` даст на выходе: " 'Name = 'John' ", а `replace_param('Name', 'John(Jhonson)')` даст на выходе: " 'Name = 'John(Jhonson)' "

Comment: @LoTerFox, поправил решение

Comment: я вам Чрезмерно Благодарен(это прям не выразить словами), простите за некоторое недопонимание которое возникло между нами, и еще раз Огромное Спасибо за помощь <3

Comment: @LoTerFox, добавил еще вариант без регулярок

Comment: Спасибо за ваше Старание, учтем и этот вариант), Вы во истину гений! Я до такого вряд ли бы додумался)))